# Python, pathos - Namespace change on new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pathos

I started using pathos.multiprocessing to remove some of the headache when pickling non-trivial objects such as logging.logger. However, I'm running into the issue that the imports are not available in a new thread. As a result I have to "re-import" those modules in that new thread. Specifically, this case will not run due to the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'os' is not defined

e Found at: multiprocess.pool

result = True, func(*args, **kwds)
```

The following code will not work even though it would work under the built-in multiprocessing module:

```
import os
import multiprocessing
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool

class SomethingDoer:
    '''Probably does some thing'''
    def doAllSomethings(self, allSomethings):
        cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1
        pool = ProcessPool(nodes=cores)
        for something in allSomethings:
            someProcess = self.doSomething, something
            pool.apipe(*someProcess)

    def doSomething(self,something):
        pathString = os.path.join(r"\foo%i"%something,"bar.log")
        print pathString
```

However, the following code will work with pathos.multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool

class SomethingDoer:
    '''Probably does some thing'''
    def doAllSomethings(self,allSomethings):
        cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1
        pool = ProcessPool(nodes=cores)
        for something in allSomethings:
            someProcess = self.doSomething, something
            pool.apipe(*someProcess)

    def doSomething(self,something):
        import os
        pathString = os.path.join(r"\foo%i"%something,"bar.log")
        print pathString
```

With the following example

```
import time
p = SomethingDoer()
p.doAllSomethings(range(3))
while 1:
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Both pieces of code should output the following output (obviously not necessarily in the same order):

```
\foo0\bar.log
\foo1\bar.log
\foo2\bar.log
```

I would like to be able to use some variation of the first snippet of code since this is consistent with the rest of the codebase. However, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `pathos` author.  If you update your `pathos` to use `multiprocess` (instead of `processing`, which is a much older fork), your code should work as intended.

```
>>> import os
>>> import pathos.helpers as multiprocessing
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool
>>> 
>>> class SomethingDoer:
...     '''Probably does some thing'''
...     def doAllSomethings(self, allSomethings):
...         cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1
...         pool = ProcessPool(nodes=cores)
...         for something in allSomethings:
...             someProcess = self.doSomething, something
...             pool.apipe(*someProcess)
...     def doSomething(self,something):
...         pathString = os.path.join(r"\foo","bar.log")
... 
>>> p = SomethingDoer()
>>> p.doAllSomethings(range(3))
>>> p.doSomething(range(3))
>>>
```

Note, you may want to get the most recent version of `dill`, which has better support for pickle-tracing of global variables.  To modify how `dill` (and thus `pathos`) handles global variables, you can do this:

```
>>> import dill
>>> dill.settings['recurse'] = True
```

No guarantee which settings are the best for your case, but it gives you options.

**EDIT:**  In response to your update.
This works:  Here you'll note that I'm doing a 'get'
instead of heaving the pool alive, and waiting for the
responses to be retrieved.

```
import os
import pathos.helpers as multiprocessing
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool

class SomethingDoer:
    '''Probably does some thing'''
    def doAllSomethings(self,allSomethings):
        cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1
        pool = ProcessPool(cores)
        for something in allSomethings:
            someProcess = self.doSomething, something
            pool.apipe(*someProcess).get()
       #pool.clear()

    def doSomething(self,something):
        pathString = os.path.join(r"\foo%i"%something,"bar.log")
        print pathString


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import time
    p = SomethingDoer()
    print p.doAllSomethings(range(3))
```

An alternative is to not use `get`, but then uncomment the `clear`… essentially destroying the pool.  `pathos` holds on to pools in a singleton,
so that multiple runs have less overhead in setting up a pool each time.

The output I get is not exactly what you predicted.

```
>$ python testme.py 
\foo0/bar.log
\foo1/bar.log
\foo2/bar.log
None
```

If you find this is unexpected behavior -- and also incorrect, please fill out a bug report.  Oh, and the settings that I suggested don't make any difference -- nor does using a "new-style" class `SomethingDoer(object)`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I have the newest pathos library since I downloaded a zip directly from https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/archive/master.zip a day before I wrote this post.

Comment: Ah… `processing` is still installed.  I didn't want to too much for folks with existing installs, so if `processing` is found, it's used.  However, it it's not found, then `multiprocess` is used.  `pathos` is finding the older library.  Try deleting `processing`.  I should perhaps change that, so it always prefers the new underlying fork.  If you have `multiprocess`, then just deleting `processing` should work.

Comment: I verified with a debugger that it is in fact using multiprocess. I hate to ask this since you've already helped so much but can you try to run the example above which now includes a print statement. The reason I'm asking is because I forgot to mention that it "fails" silently in pool.py at line 115 and without a print statement you wouldn't recognize that the method is not completing.